# a tags in my dropdowns aren't clickable on an image

Tags: html, css

so my dropdown works fine, when i click it the menu drops down, with the li's and every a tag that is not being covered by an image is clickable, so if the dropdown menu is above/in-front of an image in my page i wont be able to click it

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color:white;
    height: 3500px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family: 'Neucha', cursive;
    font-weight: 700;

}
header {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    
}
header .topLeft img {
    height: 58px;
    width: 260px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 250px;
}
.mainDiv {
    height: 550px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    animation-name: maindiv;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-duration: 0.8s;
}
@keyframes maindiv {
    from{opacity: 0;}
    to{opacity: 1;}
}
.mainDivArea {
    position: absolute;
    height: 500px;
    width: 1500px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-left: 190px;
}
.mainDivArea h1 {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 54px;
    margin: 15px 0px 36.18px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 700;

}
.mainDivArea h2 {
    height: 28px;
    width: 1015px;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin: 15px 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 250px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
.mainDivPicture {
    height: 630px;
    width: 1930px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -2;
    
}
.scheduleButton {
    height: 70px;
    width: 198px;
    padding: 25px 46px;
    border-color: rgb(29, 10, 10);
    background-color: transparent;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    position: relative;
    outline: 0!important;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 175px;
}

.scheduleButton:hover {
    background-color:#000000;
    color: white;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
.dropdown {
    height: 10vh;
    width: 10%;
    background:#FAFAFA;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 10;
    margin-left: 300px;
    z-index: 0;
    overflow: visible;
}
.salons, .services {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

.services ul, 
.salons ul {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    list-style: none;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: all;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.services a, .salons a, .about a, .contact a, .portfolio a, .somethingElse a {
    color: #404040;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.dropdown button, .portfolio, .about, .contact {
    background:none;
    border: none;
    color: #404040;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.salons li, .services li {
    background-color: white;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.salons li a, .services li a {
    width: 120px;
    height: 34px;
}
.portfolio a:hover, .about a:hover, .contact a:hover, .somethingElse a:hover {
    color: #dbd9d9;
    transition: 0.5s; 
}
.salons li a:hover, .services li a:hover {
    color: #dbd9d9;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.services button:hover, .salons button:hover, .portfolio button:hover, .about button:hover, .contact button:hover {
    color: #dbd9d9;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.services button:focus + ul{
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
    transform: translateY(20px);
}
.services button a:focus + ul {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
}
.salons button:focus + ul {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
    transform: translateY(20px);
}
.salons button a:focus + ul {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
}
.dropdown button {
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    padding-left: 25px;
    color: #404040;
}
.mobileText {
    height: 40px;
    width: 250px;
    margin-top: 37.5px;
    margin-right: 400px;
}
.mobileText p {
height: 40px;
width: 250px;
color: #000000B3;
}
.whoWeAre {
margin-top: 150px;
}
.whoWeAreTypes {
    padding-left: 280px;
    animation-name: whowearetype;
    animation-duration: 0.8s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
}
@keyframes whowearetype {
    from{opacity: 0;}
    to{opacity:1;}
}
.whoWeAreTypes img {
    padding-left: 30px;
}
.whoWeAreInfo {
    height: 535px;
    width: 1260px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-left: 310px;
    margin-top: 120px;
    animation-name: whoweareinfo;
    animation-duration: 0.8s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
}
@keyframes whoweareinfo {
    from{opacity: 0;}
    to{opacity: 1;}
}
.whoWeAreInfo .leftInfo {
    text-align: left;

}
.whoWeAreInfo .leftInfo h1 {
    font-size: 54px;
    color: #404040;
    
}
.whoWeAreInfo .rightInfo {
    justify-content: row;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 150px;
    height: 398px;
    width: 596px;
}
.whoWeAreInfo .rightInfo h2 {
    height: 112px;
    width: 595px;
    color: #00000099;
    font-size: 34px;
    margin: 0px 0px 19.92px;
}
.whoWeAreInfo .rightInfo p {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #00000099;
    margin: 16px 0px;
}
.cantWait {
    height: 685px;
    width: 1903px;
    position: relative;
}
.cantWaitImage {
    height: 685px;
    width: 1903px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    animation-name: cantwaitimg;
    animation-duration: 0.8s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
}
@keyframes cantwaitimg {
    from{opacity: 0;}
    to{opacity: 1;}
}

.cantWaitText {
    top: 300px;
    left:500px;
    position: absolute;
}
.cantWaitText h1 {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 54px;
}
.cantWaitText button {
    font-size: 32px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: transparent;
    height: 70px;
    width: 302px;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 0px;
    border-color: #ffffff;
    margin-left: 300px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
.cantWaitText button:hover {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    transition: 1s ease;
}
.bottomPortfolio {
    height: 607.41px;
    width: 1903px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 150px;
}
.portfolioTitle {
    display: flex;
     height: 42px;
    width: 1260px;
    padding: 0px 17px 17px;
    padding-left: 800px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.portfolioTitle a {
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #404040D9;
    font-size: 26px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0.8px;
    padding-left: 8px;
}
.portfolioTitle a:hover {
    color: black;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.portfolioImages {
    height: 385px;
    width: 1259px;
    margin-left: 355px;
    padding: 17px;
}
.portfolioImages img {
    height: 170px;
    width: 170px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    padding-left: 8px;  
}
.portfolioImages img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    animation-name:img-ani;
    animation-duration: 2s;   
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }             
  @keyframes img-ani {
    from{opacity:0;}
    to{opacity: 1;}
  }
  
.portfolioImagesFirst {
    display: flex;
}
.portfolioImagesSecond {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 7px;
}
footer {
    height: 356px;
    width: 1903px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #C3C9D7;
}
footer .footerTopText {
    height: 76px;
    width: 805px;
    margin-left: 840px;
}
footer .footerTopText h2 {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 27px;
    justify-content: left;
    font-weight: 700;
}
footer .footerTopText .footerTopTextEdit {
    padding-top: 25px;
}
.bottomServices {
    height: 64px;
    width: 1241px;
    margin: 0px -16px 0px 0px;
    padding: 20px 0px;
    margin-left: 660px;
    margin-top: 60px;
}
.bottomServices ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style:none;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.bottomServices ul li {
    padding-left: 50px;
    font-size: 24px;
}
.bottomServices ul li a {
    color: #ffffff;;
    list-style:none;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 26px;
}
.bottomServices ul li a:hover {
    color: black;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.copyright {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #ffffff;;
    margin-top: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 30px;
}
.address {
    padding-top:50px;
    width: 450px;
    height: 50px;
    padding-left: 250px;
}
.address ul li {
    font-size: 26px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration-color: #C1C7D7;
}
.address ul {
    padding-top: 80px;
}
```

```
body {
    height: 1650px;
}
.maindiv {
    height: 1300px;
    width: 100%;
    animation-name: maindivrrr;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-duration: 0.8s;
}
@keyframes maindivrrr {
    from{opacity: 0;}
    to{opacity: 1;}
}
.dropdown {
    background-color: #FEFFFA;
}
.dropdown button {
    background-color: #FEFFFA;
}
header {
    background-color: #FEFFFA;
}
header nav .services button, .salons button  {
    background-color: #FEFFFA;
}
.about a, .portfolio a, .contact a, .somethingElse a {
    background-color: #FEFFFA;
}
header .services  nav ul li a {
    background-color: #FEFFFA;
}
.maindivTitle {
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-left:833.5px;
    color: #404040;
    font-weight: 900;
}
.row1 {
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 270px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.card {
    background-color: transparent;
    margin-left: 30px;
    animation-name: row1rrr;
    animation-duration: 2.7s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
}
@keyframes row1rrr {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to{opacity: 1;}
}
.card-img-top {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 37.5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="productsStyle.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
    
        <div class="topLeft">
        
          <a href="index.html"><img src="https://www.carlogos.org/tire-logos/Goodyear-logo-black-5500x1200.png" alt=""></a> 
        </div>
        
        
        <nav>
            <div class="dropdown">
                
            <div class="services">
        <button>Сервисы</button>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="№">женская стрижка</a></li>
                <li><a href="№">услуги сушки феном</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">мужская стрижка</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">цвет волос</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">уход за волосами</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
            
            
             <div class="salons">
        <button>продуктьи</button>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="products.html">шампуни</a></li>
            <li><a href="creams.html">кремы</a></li>
            <li><a href=""></a></li>
            <li><a href=""></a></li>
        </ul>
             </div>
             <div class="about">
                <button><a href="about.html">около</a></button>
              </div>
                <div class="portfolio">
                    <button><a href="#">портфолио</a></button>
                </div>
                    <div class="contact">
                        <button><a href="contact.html">контакт</a></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="somethingElse">
                        <button><a href="#">еше</a></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="mobileText">
            <p>звонок / текст +995598753355</p>
        </div>
    </header> 
    <div class="maindiv" style="background-image: url('images/50-Beautiful-and-Minimalist-Presentation-Backgrounds-045.jpg');" >
        <h1 class="maindivTitle">кремы</h1>
        <div class="row1">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="images/6838_loreal-dermo-expertise-revitalift-day-cream-spf23-50ml_440_280_1524034671.png" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="card-text">Небольшой пример текста, который будет построен на названии карты и составляет основную часть содержимого карты.</p>
                </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="images/6838_loreal-dermo-expertise-revitalift-day-cream-spf23-50ml_440_280_1524034671.png" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="card-text">Небольшой пример текста, который будет построен на названии карты и составляет основную часть содержимого карты.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="images/6838_loreal-dermo-expertise-revitalift-day-cream-spf23-50ml_440_280_1524034671.png" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="card-text">Небольшой пример текста, который будет построен на названии карты и составляет основную часть содержимого карты.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="images/6838_loreal-dermo-expertise-revitalift-day-cream-spf23-50ml_440_280_1524034671.png" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="card-text">Небольшой пример текста, который будет построен на названии карты и составляет основную часть содержимого карты.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row1">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="images/6838_loreal-dermo-expertise-revitalift-day-cream-spf23-50ml_440_280_1524034671.png" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="card-text">Небольшой пример текста, который будет построен на названии карты и составляет основную часть содержимого карты.</p>
                </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="images/6838_loreal-dermo-expertise-revitalift-day-cream-spf23-50ml_440_280_1524034671.png" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="card-text">Небольшой пример текста, который будет построен на названии карты и составляет основную часть содержимого карты.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="images/6838_loreal-dermo-expertise-revitalift-day-cream-spf23-50ml_440_280_1524034671.png" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="card-text">Небольшой пример текста, который будет построен на названии карты и составляет основную часть содержимого карты.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="images/6838_loreal-dermo-expertise-revitalift-day-cream-spf23-50ml_440_280_1524034671.png" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="card-text">Небольшой пример текста, который будет построен на названии карты и составляет основную часть содержимого карты.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row1">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="images/6838_loreal-dermo-expertise-revitalift-day-cream-spf23-50ml_440_280_1524034671.png" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="card-text">Небольшой пример текста, который будет построен на названии карты и составляет основную часть содержимого карты.</p>
                </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="images/6838_loreal-dermo-expertise-revitalift-day-cream-spf23-50ml_440_280_1524034671.png" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="card-text">Небольшой пример текста, который будет построен на названии карты и составляет основную часть содержимого карты.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="images/6838_loreal-dermo-expertise-revitalift-day-cream-spf23-50ml_440_280_1524034671.png" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="card-text">Небольшой пример текста, который будет построен на названии карты и составляет основную часть содержимого карты.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="images/6838_loreal-dermo-expertise-revitalift-day-cream-spf23-50ml_440_280_1524034671.png" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="card-text">Небольшой пример текста, который будет построен на названии карты и составляет основную часть содержимого карты.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div class="address">
                <ul>
                    <li>10577</li>
                    <li>москво, россия</li>
                    <li>первомаиская</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        <div class="footerTopText">
            <h2 class="footerTopTextEdit">+995 598 75 33 55</h2>
            <h2>позвони сейчас!</h2>
        </div>
        <nav class="bottomServices">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">домой</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">около</a></li>
                <li><a href="">портфолио</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">контакт</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
            <p class="copyright">Giviko Copyright c2020. All rights reserved</p>
        </footer>  
</body>
</html>
```

as i said, i don't understand what's going on im pretty new at coding so dropdowns works basically fine, but the image is somehow blocking it (not visually) and it's not click-able

Comment: the first css is style.css and the second one is productStyle.css

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your web page, I found that your `z-index` property is set to `0` for the `.dropdown` class:

```css
.dropdown {
    height: 10vh;
    width: 10%;
    background: #FAFAFA;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 10;
    margin-left: 300px;
    z-index: 0;                  /* here */
    overflow: visible;
}
```

I changed it to `z-index: 10;` and it works :)

Comment: Thank you so much! this was the only problem that was left on my website, much appreciated!